# Applying a filter to a v-model.number input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table that binds a number of rows to each row's value, not sure how to pipe the value into the filter, which should add 1,000s separators and a currency symbol.

I've successfully used a filter for other values, but I can't get it to work for a v-model input.

```
<tbody>
<tr v-for="row in rows">
    <td><input v-model.number="row['myValue']" type="number"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

Vue.filter('toCurrency', function (value) {
    if (typeof value !== "number") { 
    return value;
    } var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { 
        style: 'currency', 
        currency: firstTable.currencyText, 
        minimumFractionDigits: 0 
    }); 
    return formatter.format(value);
});
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Filters are only intended for applying formatting to values when rendering template - specifically with text interpolation (`{{ }}`) and `v-bind`

You can't use filters with 2-way data binding (like `v-model`) because they are missing the "piece" which takes the formatted value from input and removes the formatting before storing resulting value back into the component's data model.

But `v-model` is just [syntax sugar for updating data on user input events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) so you can do:

```
<input
  v-bind:value="row['myValue'] | toCurrency"
  v-on:input="myFunctionWhichRemovesFormattingAndStoreValue($event.target.value, row)"
>
```

IMHO its much easier to just use component like [vue-cleave-component](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-cleave-component) or [vue-numeric](https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-numeric) for that....